# Most efficient and reliable method to detect if app is running in phonegap via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cordova

What is the most efficient and reliable method to detect if an app is running in phonegap, or simply inside of a mobile/desktop browser with JavaScript? I am attempting to eliminate any of the issues that prevent me from testing/debugging my phonegap apps in any browser (desktop or mobile), and create a truly universal code base for my apps.

I intend on structuring my functions with phonegap specific calls like so:

```
if (phonegapisrunning) {
    // phonegap specific javascript calls here
}
else {
    // standard javascript calls here
}
```

While searching for a solution I came across this thread:
[PhoneGap: Detect if running on desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser).

While this thread discusses this issue, I do not see a clear answer to which method is the most efficient/reliable. Should I bind to the onDeviceReady() event? Should I check window.device? Is there a more efficient or reliable way to check if an app is running in phonegap via JavsScript?

And this thread which mentions the Ripple Chrome Plugin:
[Phonegap web app in regular desktop browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159712/phonegap-web-app-in-regular-desktop-browsers?rq=1)

The Ripple tools looks like it could be a valuable tool for testing. But I am trying to make my phonegap apps run in a desktop browser without a plugin.

If it is determined that the app is not running in phonegap, I would then use useragent sniffing to determine if browser is desktop or mobile, and further separate any code if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen many answers about checking the user agent. Though those are useful for comparing which platform *on which a page was loaded*, they still do not differentiate whether running within a *cordova app's browser* or within a *regular web browser*. After a whole bunch of digging in the android cordova javascript file, I found that the following variable is set when running in a cordova app:

```
window._cordovaNative
```

Looking through the ios cordova javascript, I found:

```
window._nativeReady
```

Throw these alerts in your page before you ever load any cordova javascripts or check any user agents, etc. and compare results between loading from a web browser and loading from a cordova app that gets dynamic content:

```
alert("Android: " + window._cordovaNative);
alert("iOS: " + window._nativeReady);
```

I guess the other devices' phonegap files have different global variables, but for now, this is going to work great for me -- I hope it works well for you!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to create/call your javascript functions outside of the onDeviceReady Phonegap call.

Or maybe check what version of Cordova / Phonegap is running e.g.:

```
var string = device.cordova; // or device.phonegap

if (string == null) {
  //do non phonegappy stuff here
} else {
  //do phonegappy stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be the cleanest solution, a simple and reliable method is to create/set a global variable on deviceready:

```
var isCordovaReady = true;
```

Then:

```
if (isCordovaReady) {
    // do cordova/phonegap stuff
}
else {
    // do non cordova/phonegap stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the top answer for: [PhoneGap: Detect if running on desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser)

Although this isn't heavily documented and somewhat controversial I've been able to use this chunk of code for all my projects:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); //phone
} else {
    onDeviceReady(); //this is the browser
}
```

You can modify it a bit to work for your projects like so:

```
var phonegapisrunning = false;
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); //phone
    //change to true
    phonegapisrunning = true;

} else {
    onDeviceReady(); //this is the browser
}
```

Hope this helps !