# possible run PhoneJS in browser?

Tags: javascript, devexpress, phonejs

When I launch PhoneJS demos (HTML5/JS product from DevExpress) on my iPhone it looks correctly. But I prefer using my Safari browser to run application. On their site they show demos in browser (for example [this demo](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Demos/?url=KitchenSink&sm=3)) and they look like iOS but local demos from zip archive do not have styling.

Comment: Yes Mikhail I use PhoneJS from http://phonejs.devexpress.com. Thank you for adding this!

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/6159712/65899

Comment: Have you included all CSS files? PhoneJS is delivered with quite a big number of CSS to support multiple devices; maybe you forgot to include some of them?

Comment: @AndreyKuleshov I run demos from distribution zip and it has 5 css links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Phonegap web app in regular desktop browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159712) thread, it is necessary to use the [Ripple](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/) plugin for Google Chrome in order to run PhoneGap apps along with device-type emulation in the browser.

I have also found the [Preview on Desktop](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q500791) report in the DevExpress knowledge base, which may be helpful in your scenario.