# phonegap / cordova social sharing plugin in standard web page for desktop / mobile

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

there is a standard web page.

No cordova / phonegap app

can I use a plugin from cordova / phonegap to open native twitter / facebook for sharing?

I was thinking about using this

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

I was reading here but no clear answer was given:

[Phonegap web app in regular desktop browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159712/phonegap-web-app-in-regular-desktop-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use the cordova plugin in the standard web pages.

As the cordova plugin are the native code for android and iOS.

So if you have standard web page you have to use web plugin
As if you have angularjs in your web page then you can use [angular social share](https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare) plugin for sharing.

Hope this helps